TTY-based big-picture system status overview for Linux
I'm currently trying to set up a Kubernetes cluster with Rancher on my vSphere/ESXi instance. In vSphere, there's a list of VMs, and when you click on one, the page that opens has a thumbnail of what the VM's monitor is showing:

This isn't particularly useful right now, because all it's ever going to show is a bunch of TTY lines from what cloud-init is outputting. Moreover, it's fairly pointless to open the console, because the Rancher nodes are meant to be ephemeral: if it misbehaves you don't log into it to fix the problem, you destroy it and make a new one from scratch.
However, since the display thumbnail is there, I'd like to be able to do something useful with it, like show some kind of node status on there. For example, it could fill the screen with red when the node is overloaded, or being destroyed.
Are there any such programs that would show a full-screen display representing some part of a system's status?
